# Insert picture into picturebox from a looped class?

Tags: c#

Well my goal is simply to print the picture, and everytime it does the value i increases by 1, by doing this the picture will switch to the next and so on. I'm using a class as operator for the main code below. The ???? part is my issue, it just never works.

```
Class (1)
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing; //för att kunna lagra Image

namespace KortlekenEgen
{
    class Kort
    {
        //datamedlemmar
        public int siffra;
        public Image bild;

        //konstruktor
        public Kort(int nr, Image card)
        {
            this.siffra = nr;
            this.bild = card;
        }
    }
}


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace KortlekenEgen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //skapar 2 objekt för att lagra förra och det nya kortet.
        Kort old;
        Kort ny;
        //skapar 1 vektor som ska lagra 13 Kortobjekt (1 färg)
        Kort[] kortlek = new Kort[13];
        Random slump = new Random(); //skapar slumpobjekt för att slumpa plats i vektorn
        int plats = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //lägger in hjärter ess på plats 0 i vektorn
            kortlek[1] = new Kort(1, Image.FromFile("Bilder/h1.png")); 
        }

        private void btnDraKort_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0, j = 1; i<=13; i++, j++)
            kortlek[i] = new Kort(j, Image.FromFile("Bilder/h" + i + ".png"));
            //generera slumptal och tilldela det till variabeln plats
            if(rbnHogre.Checked == true)
            {
                pbxNy.Image = ?????????
            }
            if(rbnLagre.Checked == true)
            {

            }
            //hämta objektet på positionen plats i vektorn och lägg i objektet ny

            //jämför med old

            //sist i denna metod lägger ni in objektet ny i old.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping pbxNy.Image to be? What do you mean it 'it just never works'?

Comment: I want to insert it, pbx.ny is basically the image holder.

Comment: _"The ???? part is my issue, it just never works"_ - that's because it's not valid c# code

Comment: But what do you mean by 'it just never works'? Do you mean it never evaluates rbnHogre.Checked to true? Do you mean you've tried inserting something but you get an error?

Comment: Well, i did put ???? there since i didn't know it. what i tried was pbxny.Image = (Image)kortlek; and some others but i never got it to work, this code works with a simple picture, the problem i'm having is inserting pictures who are in a loop to the GUI each time you click on the button

Comment: What is the definition of 'Kort'? Basically it looks to contain 2 values, the first is a number (int) and the second is the image. So you will need to cast kortlek[i] to an image like you did but use the property that defines the image.

Comment: If you have loaded iimages into kortlek why not assign one from there? You don't show us that class, so we can't know exactly how it works; something like pbxNy.Image = kortlek [1].img may be it, but you need to __show us the Kort class__!

Comment: @TaW surely we need to see 'Kort' not kortlek? kortlek is just an array of 'Kort's, whatever they are.

Comment: Alright, updated with the class, basically i'm trying to get images from a folder > put them in a order that counts up (loop), each time you press that button the value increases and thus the higher picture is shown.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @Ayylamo - if my answer worked for you please mark it as the answer. I see that you have asked a few questions here and never marked an answer as correct. If someone has spent their time helping you and given you the correct answer it's only fair you mark it as correct. In addition, this will help future users who come across the question to see how the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it to work using this:

```
pbxNy.Image = (Image)kortlek[i].bild
```

Now updated with the correct property name.